# How do you open FileMaker 13 Advanced using atomac.launchAppByBundlePath?

Tags: python, automated-tests

I've decided to automate some tests for a FileMaker 13 Advanced solution with atomac. I've discovered that FileMaker 13 Advanced as the same bundle id as FileMaker 16 Advanced ... ouch.

```
import atomac
atomac.launchAppByBundleId('com.filemaker.client.advanced12')
```

Launches FileMaker 16 Advanced which is unfortunate since FileMaker 16 Advanced won't work with the FileMaker server I am testing.

I tried editing the Info.plist to see if that would make a difference.

```
import atomac
atomac.launchAppByBundleId('com.filemaker.client.advanced13')
```

resulted in

```
RuntimeError: Error launching specified application.
```

I then tried using launchAppByBundlePath

```
atomac.launchAppByBundlePath('/Applications/FileMaker Pro 13 Advanced/FileMaker Pro Advanced 13.app')
```

and I got

```
ValueError: NSInvalidArgumentException - Class OC_PythonObject: no such selector: count
```

How do you open FileMaker 13 Advanced using atomac.launchAppByBundlePath?

Found a temporary workaround using atomac.getAppRefByPid 
https://python-atomac.blogspot.com.au/p/blog-page_20.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the issue related to something with atomac and anaconda python version 3.x.

I changed the path settings to reference only python27 and the issue was resolved.